# Binding a code-behind defined property to a DataContext property in XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

I'm trying to bind a property that was defined in Page code-behind to a ListView.DataContext property in XAML, but for some reason it's not working in the way that I thought, when I run the app the ListView.DataContext is not being set and remains null, can someone please help me with that?

I looked for some similar questions but most of them solve the problem by setting the DataContext manually in the code-behind, but I'd like to do that from XAML.

#### MainPage.xaml

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="CustomControls.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:CustomControls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <StackPanel>
        <ListView
            DataContext="{Binding Path=MyMarket, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Products}"
            Header="{Binding Path=Name}">

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Id}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

#### MainPage.xaml.cs

```cs
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

namespace CustomControls
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public Market MyMarket { get; private set; }

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;

            this.MyMarket = new Market
            {
                Name = "My Market",
                Products = new ObservableCollection<Product>
                {
                    new Product { Id = 123, Description = "qwerty" },
                    new Product { Id = 234, Description = "wertyu" }
                }
            };
        }
    }

    public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

    public class Market
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bind to the page, so you have to do that at the very top of your XAML:

```
<Page
[..]
DataContext="{Binding MyMarket, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
```

Then you should be able to hook into that like this:

```
<ListView
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Products}"
    Header="{Binding Path=Name}">
[..]
```

Now just switch the lines in your constructor so that your elements are already there before the page is built:

```
this.MyMarket = new Market
{
    Name = "My Market",
    Products = new ObservableCollection<Product>
    {
        new Product { Id = 123, Description = "qwerty" },
        new Product { Id = 234, Description = "wertyu" }
    }
};
this.InitializeComponent();

this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
```

You should consider using Viewmodel classes later on.

Comment: Fred, I just tried that and it didn't worked, as I wrote in this comment to the other question, do you have any idea? I thought this would be the correct way even though it doesn't seem to work like that.

Comment: It works. There was just an initialization flaw. I edited my answer. Also you can leave the DataContext tag in your list view out - it's obsolete in this solution. I edited that as well.

Comment: Fred, you're awesome dude, thanks for this great answer? Please do me one last favor and correct me if I me wrong, so the property initialization has to be done before the call to `InitializeComponent` because when I do it after the DataContext property has already been assigned the MyMarket property has not been instantiated yet and as it won't refresh the UI for changes on it when I assign this new instance to it nothing happens?

Comment: Yes, that's about right. The page binds to MyMarket - which is null at that moment - and doesn't know that you are changing the reference.

Answer (score 1):

`{RelativeSource Mode=Self}` refers to the current element, in this case `ListView`, so it's not what you want. The easiest way is to give a name to the root element (the `Page`), for instance `"root"`, and specify `ElementName=root` in your binding.

Comment: Ok, I added the `x:Name="mainPage"` to the `Page` declaration and replaced `asd` with `qwe` in the ListView declaration and it worked thanks for that Thomas, but one more question you said I wasn't referring to the root element, so I tried to remove the `DataContext` property setting from the `ListView` declaration and added it to the `Page` declaration even though it didn't worked, can you explain me that? In this last context `self` would referring to `Page` right so shouldn't it work in the same way?